# Building an app from a wordpress site

Tags: android, wordpress, cordova, phonegap-build

I want to create an android app from my existing wordpress site.

I have a news site running on wordpress whose theme was built my me. I would like to create an app for the same site. Basically it just has to list posts available on the site.

I am aware of some plugins which would do it automatically but I would like to know if it can be done using phonegap.

I need some help (pointers) as to how I can pull posts from my wordpress site and reflect it on the app.

Comment: Take a look at [WP-REST API](http://wp-api.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good and complete tutorial for build this app using ionic framework:
[Link video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbopML8dnqg)

Answer (score 0):

There are options, like AppPresser, they convert your WordPress website into a mobile app, publish on the app stores for a fee.